# Sort text file with cat and sort concatenation

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, cat

I got a txt file with some content looking like

```
stuff,stuff,2012-12-12
morestuff,morestuff,2012-09-09
evenmorestuff,yeah,2012-08-02
```

and I want to use cat and sort to get them reverse ordered by the date as an output on my command-line by concatenation.

Comment: Why `cat`?  It doesn't change anything; it doesn't do anything useful in this context.  And the sample data isn't compelling; it is already in reverse order of date (most recent first).

Answer (score 2):

not sure why you think you need to `cat` a file into sort, but here are 2 options

```
  cat yourFile | sort -t, -k3r

  sort -t, -k3r yourFile
```

To test this I did

```
echo "stuff,stuff,2012-12-12
morestuff,morestuff,2012-09-09
evenmorestuff,yeah,2012-08-02" \
| sort -t, -k3r
```

**output**

```
stuff,stuff,2012-12-12
morestuff,morestuff,2012-09-09
evenmorestuff,yeah,2012-08-02
```

And finally, you can overwrite your existing file using the `-o` option like

```
 sort -t, -o yourFile -k3r yourFile
```

Thanks to  @karakfa for reminding me your your requirement for reverse order sort. This is accomplished by adding an `r` to the key specification, hence `-k3r`.

IHTH

Comment: for reverse order (descending) you'll need `-k3r`

Comment: Thanks, missed that. was going to review ;-)

Comment: thanks! is there the possibilty to do it for ; as the separator too?

Comment: @Applecow: Of course.  You choose your character after the `-t`; if it is a shell metacharacter (which `;` is, but `,` is not), enclose it in single quotes: `-t ';'`.  Using single-quotes always works; it isn't always necessary.  (If you need to use a single quote as the separator, then you can use `-t "'"` or `-t \'`, both of which also work for other characters, but double quotes will be a nuisance with back-ticks and double quotes, etc.) The delimiter character can be attached to the `-t` option or separated by one or more spaces as suits your whim.